# Detect ajax error with Featherlight.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, featherlight.js

Is there a way to detect if the resource requested by ajax-featherlight returns an error (i.e 500 response code)?

At the moment, I'm using feathelight's attribute `loading` to set an animated spinner but there's no way to alert the user if the request failed - it will look like the content is still loading.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't check right now, but FL should detect it. If not, file an issue and you could use jquery ajax events in  the meantime